# Someone has to walk 500 steps, and each step takes 2 seconds, how long will it take to arrive if they're at their 17th step?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Sometimes I can't wrap my head around simple math lol. Hopefully the title speaks for itself. I understand it will take 1000 seconds or roughly 16 minutes from the first step until arrival, but can't wrap my head around how to calculate how much time will be left if they're at their 5th, 22th, 436th or whatever step.

Hope my question is clear, thank you.

Comment: Hint: How many steps are remaining after the 17th step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have just finished the 17th step, we can understand this as they have spent 34 seconds, so we just have to subtract this from 1000. A formula here would be $2\cdot(500-17)$.

If they have just finished the i-th step, the formula for the time would be $2\cdot(500-i)$.

Comment: Oh of course haha! Thanks for your help.